# variables variables

Tags: php, php7

¿Es logico utilizar este metodo?

```
<?php

$valor = 0;

for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
   ${"variable_".$i} = $valor;
   $valor += 1;
}

echo $variable_5; //imprime 4;

?>
```

No sé si sea una buena practiva para acortar lineas de codigo, y tampoco estoy seguro si esas variables se sigan manteniendo si por ejemplo despues de 1000 lineas la quiera volver a llamar.

Comment: ¿Y por que no usar un arreglo? (`array`)

Comment: checa si lo que tienes en el for como variable esta bien o te equivocaste al copiar y pegar tu script

Comment: Al menos en ese mismo documento de php vas a tener acceso porque no  llamas a esa variable desde otro archivo para ver si tienes acceso. Claro incluyendo ese archivo al actual que tienes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la documentación de PHP, se refieren a esto como [`variables variables`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.variable.php):

> #### Variables variables
>
> A veces es conveniente tener nombres de variables variables. Dicho de otro modo, son nombres de variables que se pueden definir y usar dinámicamente.

Es una *variación* de la función [`eval( )`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.eval.php) (existente también en otros lenguajes), pero muy limitada. Si `eval( )` te permite evaluar sentencias mas o menos complejas, las `variables variables` solo te permiten acceder (para obtener el valor o para establecerlo) a una única variable. También puedes pensar en ellas como *punteros* a otras variables (salvando las distancias).

Se pueden usar mediante 2 sintaxis distintas:

```
$name = 'hola';
$$name = 'mundo !'

echo $name $hola;
```

> 'hola mundo !'

O mediante la forma (a mi juicio mas clara) `${}`. Copio y pego la gran explicación de la documentación:

> Para usar variables variables con *arrays* hay que resolver un problema de ambigüedad. Si se escribe `$$a[1]`, el intérprete necesita saber si nos referimos a utilizar `$a[1]` como una variable, o si se pretendía utilizar `$$a` como variable y el índice `[1]` como índice de dicha variable. La sintaxis para resolver esta ambigüedad es: `${$a[1]}` para el primer caso y `${$a}[1]` para el segundo.

Esta misma sintaxis es perfectamente válido incluso sin usar ningún *array*, mejorando la lectura del código (puesto que limita claramente la parte `variable variable`).

Un último punto: se puede utilizar **mas de un nivel de `variable variable` a la vez**:

```
<?php
$Bar = 'a';
$Foo = 'Bar';
$World = 'Foo';
$Hello = 'World';
$a = 'Hello';

echo $a; // Hello
echo $$a; // World
echo $$$a; // Foo
echo $$$$a; // Bar
echo $$$$$a; // a
echo $$$$$$a; // Hello
echo $$$$$$$a; // World
?>
```

Comment: Genial, tu aporte me aclaro mucho el tema. muchas gracias.